# ntheorem placement of thmmarks wrong

Tags: ntheorem

I have the following problem with ntheorem: Whenver an ntheorem environment ends with a displayed equation, the thmmark is completely misplaced. For instance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremsymbol{*}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{Def}
    \label{DefFoo}
    Lorem ipsum
    \begin{align*}
        x=y, && y = z
    \end{align*}
        Lorem ipsum
    \begin{align}
        \label{EqB}
        a = b
    \end{align}
    %Lorem ipsum %comment this line in to make it work
\end{Def}

\end{document}
```

Yields: [image: wrong placement]

However if one comments in the last line, it is correct:[image: correct placement]

Comment: Rerun!, my `theoremsymbol` doesn't appear where you showed, but it appears below of the *tag* `(1)`. I don't like that `*` is in *italic* after of *Lorem ipsum*; you must define it like `\theoremsymbol{\textup{*}}`.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is due to run only once after of to do some changes. If you change something, you should run twice.

Comment: Hm, that's strange. I ran the non-working example ten times now and the theoremsymbol is still misplaced. This phenomenon seems to be independent of the symbol I use (or if I use \textup). :(

Comment: You can place a nonbreaking space, i.e. the character `~`, instead of the last line of text which is now commented out. This is just a quick hack to make it work, though ... on the other hand, you will not get any better results, because the equation tag (1) is in the spot where the star would really want to be. This seems to be some misbehaviour of ntheorem indeed, it does not even work when you use `\documentclass[leqno]{article}`.